# Is there a clean way to prevent windows.h from creating a near & far macro?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dos

Deep down in WinDef.h there's this relic from the segmented memory era:

```
#define far
#define near
```

This obviously causes problems if you attempt to use near or far as variable names.  Any clean workarounds? Other then renaming my variables?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can safely undefine them, contrary to claims from others. The reason is that they're just macros's. They only affect the preprocessor between their definition and their undefinition. In your case, that will be from early in windows.h to the last line of windows.h. If you need extra windows headers, you'd include them after windows.h and before the #undef. In your code, the preprocessor will simply leave the symbols unchanged, as intended.

The comment about older code is irrelevant. That code will be in a separate library, compiled independently. Only at link time will these be connected, when macros are long gone.

Comment: +1 for correcting the insanity of most of the other responses.

Comment: I agree with the comment about older code being irrelevant, but I don't agree with the argument. Separate libraries include header files that could use `near` and `far`.

Answer (score 11):

Undefine any macros you don't want after including `windows.h`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#undef near
#undef far
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe:

```
#undef near
#undef far
```

could be dangerous though...

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to undefined near and far everywhere.  But when you need to use the variable names, you can use the following to undefine the macro locally and add it back when you are done.

```
#pragma push_macro("near")
#undef near
//your code here.
#pragma pop_macro ("near")
```

Answer (score -3):

Best not to. They are defined for backwards compatibility with older code - if you got rid of them somehow and then later needed to use some of that old code you'd be broken.

Comment: 32-bit and 64-bit Windows only support a flat memory model, not segmented with 2 sizes of pointers.  If you have code that still uses `far char *p = ...` or whatever the right syntax was, then 1. remove that.  2. you already know you need these definitions to compile that ancient code and aren't looking for an answer to this question.