# #define far, #define near Windef.h

Tags: c++, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a clean way to prevent windows.h from creating a near & far macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118774/is-there-a-clean-way-to-prevent-windows-h-from-creating-a-near-far-macro)

What's the point of these two defines in Windef.h?

```
#define far     /* nothing */
#define near    /* nothing */
```

I know it has to do with [near and far](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_near_far_and_huge_pointers_in_C) pointers and the fact they're no longer used, but, is it safe to `#undef` them, so I can use `near` and `far` as function and variable names in my code?

Or, should I simply avoid it and never use `near` and `far` as identifiers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reuse them. The last thing you need is to have to repeatedly explain to people that they aren't the old-school ornaments.

If it is critical to your app, you might consider using capitalized versions (since identifiers are case sensitive) - the compiler will catch typos when you mess up.

Just accept that this is cruft from the good old days when computers were still made from metal.

Comment: And a 80286 machine weighed 45 lbs!

Answer (score 1):

Although undefining this empty macros is actually harmless, I would definitely avoid to reuse some well-known macro... It's like using `goto` as a variable name just because you are not using it as a keyword...