# near and far get defined in gl3w?

Tags: c, parameters

I am getting a `parameter name omitted` error with this code

```
#include <GL3/gl3w.h>

void f(int near, int far) {

}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118774/is-there-a-clean-way-to-prevent-windows-h-from-creating-a-near-far-macro) question I suspected gl3w included WinDef.h but I am not able to find it included in the sources. What is the source of this problem and how can it be corrected?

Comment: That question's accepted answer seems reasonable. If you're looking for the story, there used to be near pointers and far pointers, which are now obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

near and far were used to indicate types of pointers, and are likely to be defined as

```
#define near
#define far
```

Which leaves you with

```
void f(int , int )
{

}
```

Which is an invalid function definition in C. (arguments must have a name). either undefine them (`#undef`) or change the argument names. Note that this is not a problem in function declaration (i.e. `void foo(int, int);` - as in header files) only in function definitions.

Specifically, **gl3w.h** contains [**gl3.h**](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/gl3.h) which contains **windows.h**

Answer (score 3):

To be sure the problem do not come from `WinDef.h`, you can try to undefine `near` and `far`, to see if it works.

```
#undef far
#undef near
```

The error seems to match with the behavior of this definitions. Is `near` and `far` are defined as empty macros, your parameters won't have identifiers.