# peculiar bug - parameter doesn't exist yet builds, until name of parameter changes then it breaks more favourably

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parameters, x86-64, windows-10-desktop

[image]Note: f32 is a float, m4x4 is a linear 4 by 4 matrix.
I have a function:
`inline m4x4 Orthographic(f32 left, f32 right, f32 bottom, f32 top, f32 nearr, f32 far)`

you may notice that its got a misspelling. This is because if I call the parameter 'near' the code doesn't compile. When I change it to nearr and compile, it gets worse, as far no longer exists. Not in the debugger, not in the disassembly, the name just vanishes and the behaviour of the code breaks. eg. I was using the values -1 for near and 1 for far, this had the behaviour of flipping and inverting a triangle I was rendering. When I changed the function signature to the following, the code worked as expected:
`inline m4x4 Orthographic(f32 left, f32 right, f32 bottom, f32 top, f32 nearplane, f32 farplane)`

By changing the names the code was magically okay. One thing I've observed is it seems to be related to the character r.

I've changed the names, switched the parameter orders around, stepped through in the debugger, changed the body of the function and looked at the disassembly etc The order of the parameters doesn't change anything. The trailing r seems to be significant but I have no idea why, I'm very confused. My knowledge of assembly is perhaps too weak. Below is the code copied and pasted unmodified with comments I made when trying to figure it out late night a few days ago when I was last at the computer.

```
    inline m4x4  // TODO go through the dissasembly 
inline m4x4 Orthographic(f32 left, f32 right, f32 nearr, f32 far, f32 bottom, f32 top)
    //NOTE this is also broken so its not just param order 
//Orthographic(f32 left, f32 right, f32 bottom, f32 top, f32 nearr, f32 far)
//Orthographic(f32 left, f32 right, f32 bottom, f32 top, f32 near, f32 far)
{ // TODO this is broken because far doesn't seem to exist???   if i change near to nearr then it compiles but far doesnt exist, if i set it as near then it fails to compile
    m4x4 Result;
    f32 dw = right - left;
    f32 dh = top - bottom; 
    //f32 dd = far - near;
    f32 dd = far - nearr;

    f32 width = right + left;
    f32 height = top + bottom;
    //f32 depth = far + near;
    f32 depth = far + nearr;

    Result = 
    {
        2/dw, 0.0f, 0.0f, -(width/dw),
        0.0f, 2/dh, 0.0f, -(height/dh),
        0.0f, 0.0f, -2/dd, -(depth/dd),
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    return (Result);
}
#else
    inline m4x4
Orthographic(f32 left, f32 right, f32 bottom, f32 top, f32 nearplane, f32 farplane)
{ //TODO find out what the deal is with f32 near because this shit is crazy and it caused a painful bug
    m4x4 Result;
    f32 dw = right - left;
    f32 dh = top - bottom; 
    f32 dd = farplane - nearplane;

    f32 width = right + left;
    f32 height = top + bottom;
    f32 depth = farplane + nearplane;

    Result = 
    {
        2/dw, 0.0f, 0.0f, -(width/dw),
        0.0f, 2/dh, 0.0f, -(height/dh),
        0.0f, 0.0f,-2/dd, -(depth/dd),
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    return (Result);
}



#endif
```

I expected that all the parameters should show in the debugger and that their values should appear in the logic... I also expect that when the additional r is added to the name of the ident, it shouldn't succesfully build and run, certainly not in the debugger at the very least, and yet...

When the additional r is removed from nearr and it fails to compile, the following is the output at the command line.
maths.h(443): error c2059: syntax error: ';'
maths.h(448): error c2059: syntax error: ';'

I haven't seen the significance of that error in my scouring the codebase. 443 and 448 are in the body of the function and are the lines with the far and nearr parameters.

Edit: my workflow involves working in vim and compiling at the commandline, I use visual studio as my debugger.

---

Observe the issue fully using the following code sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#if 0 //change to 1 to fix
#undef near
#undef far
#endif 

float BrokenByMacro(float near, float far)
{
    float Result = near + far;

    return(Result);
}

int main()
{
    float MyFloat = BrokenByMacro(1, 2);
    printf("%f", MyFloat);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Do you use any windows headers? Do you compile with MSVC extensions disabled? What compiler version? It looks like some sort of identifier pollution/conflict, since, IRC, `near` and `far` macro/keywords were used for pointers in DOS/early WinAPI days.

Comment: Nice one, I suspected a macro at first but I didn't pursue that as far as I should have!  I use a unity build so just adding #undef far #undef near after inlcuding windows.h fixed the issue. far and near are terrible names for macros. I should really remove windows.h and only use what I need out of it.

Comment: ps. please provide an answer so I can mark you as answered

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] so I can retract my vote-to-close-as-off-topic. ;)

Comment: In the old days (especially when dealing with 16-bit code) the compilers had `near` and `far` as type modifiers (like `volatile`). Those were eventually dropped by the compilers but to retain some compatibility they were defined by the preprocessor as macros that do nothing. One may argue that they are bad names for macros, but they are macros that exist to mitigate issues with references to `near` and `far` keywords that may have been previously used by compilers/code.

Comment: I added a code sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The reason I stopped looking for a macro is because I use a unity build and the windows.h include was in the platform section of my code base. I wish it would expand to an observable value in the debugger like oxdeadbeef instead, though I'm guilty of using macros that expand to nothing too in my own code. Feels different when its a widely used include though, seems misguided.

Comment: Then again in this instance it wouldn't have compiled anyway. Generally I like macros but there is poor support for them, they should be a lot more powerful than they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the error format you are using MSVC and likely affected by unhygienic includes of Windows headers somewhere in your project (`windef.h` or `windows.h` being the likely culprits).

These headers have a tendency to define a lot of macros that frequently conflict with the user code in subtle ways. In your particular case you seem to be affected by `far` and `near` macros, which usually expand to nothing.

As suggested in this related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118774/is-there-a-clean-way-to-prevent-windows-h-from-creating-a-near-far-macro) you can simply `#undef` them in the appropriate place. Although I would also consider your `#include` hierarchy to limit windows-specific headers' scope.